# Is it possible to know how script was loaded

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have script `source.js`.
There are two ways two load it:

1. `<script src="source.js"></script>`
2. via `document.createElement` and `appendChild`

Is it possible from inside `source.js` to know about the way of loading?

Comment: They should be the same, and there's really no reason the script should have to know how it was loaded ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: No.

You *could* change the `script` tag to have an extra attribute

`<script src="source.js" data-scripttag="true"></script>`

Then in your `source.js` file you could see if that attribute is present on the tag. If it is, it was called via the script tag. However, I assume from the question that you aren't able to modify the HTML calling the script (third party integration?).

This example snippet won't work in SO, but should give an idea of a way to achieve this if you can edit the HTML.

```js
// foo.js

var scriptTags = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scripttag]');
if (scriptTags.length === 1) {
  // Called via script tag
} else {
  // injected
}
```

```html
<script src="foo.js" data-scripttag="true"></script>

<script>
  var fs = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.src = 'foo.js';
  fs.parentNode.insertBefore(s, fs)
</script>
```

Comment: How can the script tag's attribute be accessed from within the included file?

Comment: Well, you could get all elements that have a data attribute that you specify, in this case `data-scripttag`. You could also find the element by it's source attribute.